# Django 1.8 : Customized 'User with few other fields' authentication with superuser management

Tags: python, angularjs, django, mongodb

After digging many solutions and tutorials, I have confused what is the right way to proceed for my problem, since most of them written in older version of Django. I want a simple user management

- Default Django User model + few added fields is fine
- Angular front-end will be used for login, logout and to display user specific content, a dashboard and their profile
- Next thing to follow is to integrate Mongo db backend replacing default db

I also found out substitution, tweaking user management broke things. I want clean and minimal approach so that it is flexible for code maintenance. I appreciate all sort of suggestions out of experience or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

First: Extending the user model - [django doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

You can set your own user model using the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` variable in your setitngs. Your new user model needs to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`.

---

Second: To interact with angular and django - [rest api - tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Tastypie is a module in django to create a REST API from your modules. Thi essentially converts models to json formats - which can be used in Angular JS (and can be imported into an angular JS model)

---

Third: Mongo in django - [django-mongodb-engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Django doesnt support mongodb (or any NoSQL) db by default. So,this has to be done by an extension or a django variant. I went on a spree to find the best NoSQL client for django a year back and could not find any which could be used for a production environment.

If you want NoSQL - I suggest don't use django. Ruby or NodeJS may be more preferrable

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply !

Comment: Please accept the answer if I was able to answer what you're looking for

Comment: @AJK what are the issues with Django and MongoDB? I'm digging into this too and it seems like django-mongodb-engine supports embedded documents and relationships. 
For a simple case where Djangois only used for authentication and API, what are the limitations of MongoDB?

Comment: @Alain1405 - for simple scenarios it isnt an issue - but the abstraction doesnt work sometimes. Also, when I tried it - it wasnt possible to install it with pypi, and `python setup.py install` spewed a lot of errors. But again, this was quite a while back and the maintainers seem to have been busy the past year - so, maybe the support has become much better :)

Comment: If you do happen to try it out and think that django+mongo is a good combination now - do edit my post with more current info so that it's beneficial to others !